# How to install vtiger CRM 6 on Wampserver

Tags: php, crm, vtiger

I am new in vtiger CRM. I placed the extracted vtiger CRM 6 into the wamp/www path. But when I browse the path in the browser, it shows error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function Execute() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\vtigercrm\include\database\PearDatabase.php on line 354
```

What else I have to be done? Anyone please help me. Thanks

Comment: Where are you browsing to http://localhost/vtiger6 (or whatever your folder is called)?

Comment: I am browsing localhost/vtigercrm. But nothing shows

Comment: Ok firstly be sure your folder is called vtigercrm exactly as you are typing in the browser. Secondly create a new folder in www ie test and put a simple index.html that says hello or similar and make sure you can navigate to this http://localhost/test. If not there may be an issue with apache. If you can browse to the page and get an output, then likelihood is that there is an error when accessing the vtiger directory and you have errors turned off, hence no output. So you would need to edit your php.ini file to show errors to debug further

Comment: You are right. I edit my php.ini file and the error shows. The error is :       Fatal error: Call to a member function Execute()

Comment: Unfortunately from here you will need to do a few searches for vtiger and this error to see if any else is experiencing this issue. But now you have the error, debugging will be much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you get this error while installing new vtiger 6 . This error is due to the browser cache, cookies and session of previously used vtiger. So clear your browser cache and cookies and exit your browser and reopen before you start installing a new vtiger instance